# TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my coding for dynamic field validation.
if i use this function i got 'TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null' this kind of error.

```
function sr_answer_val(){
  var cnt=parseInt(document.getElementById("add_field_cnt").value);
  var submitAllow=true;
  for(var i=1;i<cnt;i++){
    if(document.getElementById("cust_field_"+i).value ==''){
      alert('Answer Should be Mandatory');
      submitAllow=false;
      return false;     
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check the HTML, if there are really all elements present (at the time of execution) you want to access.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: Please provide your HTML markup too. Check if the element __add_field_cnt__ and __cust_field_<n>__ exist in yur page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your custom fields are not all defined, so when you try to acces one of them it is undefined.

Check the existence of the element before accesing it like:

```
function sr_answer_val() {
    var cnt = parseInt(document.getElementById("add_field_cnt").value);
    var submitAllow = true;
    for (var i = 1; i < cnt; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById("cust_field_" + i) && document.getElementById("cust_field_" + i).value == '') {
            alert('Answer Should be Mandatory');
            submitAllow = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/X3ZnQ/

Answer (score 0):

There's for sure no element with id named "add_field_cnt" in your html. Check if there's no any typo.

Answer (score 0):

Your element 
`add_field_cnt` is (DOM) not loaded/created.

I guess you're loading the js in head, instead do it at the bottom of `body` or use [`document.ready`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799981/1671639)

Answer (score 0):

The element with id passed to `getElementById()` does not exist. So, you can do a null check

```
var elem = document.getElementById("add_field_cnt");
if(typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null) {
    var cnt = parseInt(document.getElementById(elem).value);
    .......// do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no element with the ID **add_field_cnt** so you are getting this error

```
var cnt=parseInt(document.getElementById("add_field_cnt").value);
```

please check your element is Created or not with **add_field_cnt** ID.

i hope so.